# 2 Vertical scroll bars appeared randomly in my HTML

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have built a website for my customer. Today, I checked the website and I saw that there are two vertical scrollbars suddenly. I dont know how it came.

I googled it a lot and they say it because of the css.

```
  overflow: auto
```

I looked for that overflow thing and I couldnt it find it. I found a simple tip on stackoverflow like below. I added that piece of code. It didt remove that weird scrollbar, intead it remove the real usefull scrollbar.

```
  $('html').css('overflow', 'hidden');
```

how can I fix this? my website is [this](http://turunch.net)

Comment: If you have two scrollbars, you've messed up in the CSS; and now have one scrollbar on an element, and probably another on `html` or `body` etc.

Comment: Can you post the URL?

Comment: You must post your code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it in **CSS** adding

```
.jPanelMenu, body {
overflow-x: initial;
}
```

or

```
.jPanelMenu, body {
    overflow-x: visible;
    }
```

or in **JS** `$('body').css('overflow-x', 'initial');`

Comment: your js code worked. how did I mess up the code, I didnt get it

Answer (score 2):

```
.jPanelMenu, body {overflow:initial}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood.

you need to set in CSS height: auto;